# How to solve SonarQube unused parameter rule in an optional protocol method?

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube

I have some optional methods in a protocol which have parameters that aren't being used as it has no implementation.

I can't find a way to satisfy SonarQube rule "Remove unused parameter" without getting rid of the parameter. Any clues?

```
public protocol InfoProtocol {
    func getInfo(viewController: UIViewController)
    func setInfo(viewController: UIViewController)
}

public extension InfoProtocol {
    func getInfo(viewController: UIViewController) {
        // default implementation
    }

    func setInfo(viewController: UIViewController) {
        // default implementation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making the methods inside `InfoProtocol` as **`optional`**, in case you neither want to implement them everywhere, not want to to give any default implementation with `protocol extension`, i.e.

```
@objc protocol InfoProtocol {
    @objc optional func getInfo(viewController: UIViewController)
    @objc optional func setInfo(viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, InfoProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

In the above code, since the methods in `InfoProtocol` are `optional`, so not implementing them in `ViewController` doesn't throw any `compile-time error`.